# Invalid javascript Date in Google Chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, datetime

The below javascript convertion returns invalid date while ruuning application in google Chrome.But it returns correct datetime in Internet Explorer.

```
 var custDate=new Date("05/23/2104 10:15PM");
```

Please help.

Comment: Check your browser localization settings. There might be different configs.

Comment: Check the documentation for [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). Only a few date formats are officially supported, and yours is not one of them.

Comment: to make the time format common in all browsers, what will be the time input?

Comment: most common is `unix_timestamp * 1000`

Comment: see this http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari

Comment: Try something like this `new Date("05/23/2104 10:15:00 GMT");`

Comment: if I use Date("05/23/2104 10:15:00 GMT"); How can I know is it in AM or PM?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari) article.

```
new Date("05/23/2104 10:15:00 GMT");
```

Examples:

```
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07); // yyyy, mm-1, dd
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00); // yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mm, ss
var d = new Date("02/07/2011"); // "mm/dd/yyyy"
var d = new Date("02/07/2011 11:05:00"); // "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
var d = new Date(1297076700000); // milliseconds
var d = new Date("Mon Feb 07 2011 11:05:00 GMT"); // ""Day Mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT/UTC
```

Comment: How to know the time is in AM or PM?

Answer (score 0):

also,

```
new Date() // current date and time
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

or

```
d1 = new Date("October 13, 1975 11:13:00")
d2 = new Date(79,5,24)
d3 = new Date(79,5,24,11,33,0)
```

Comment: How to know the time is in AM or Pm?

Comment: hours are defined between 0 and 23

Answer (score -2):

for chrome use this syntax :

```
new Date("05/23/2014 22:15");
```

normaly, it will solved

Comment: This works in all browsers as well

`new Date('2001/01/31 12:00:00')`
``
That is the format of :
`"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`